# table-based forms?

Tags: html, forms

Looking for sites which offer templates for creating styled table-based web page forms.

Similar to css-based forms at:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/

(please no css is better than tables discussions)

Comment: You might get more luck if you expanded on the requirements. For example, WHY are you restricted to tables, rather than CSS?

Answer (score 3):

This is like asking for an example of GOTO statement best practices. Your just asking for trouble, no matter the intent!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about sites which offer templates, but 37 Signals use tables with their forms. Like [this one](https://signup.37signals.com/basecamp/Max/signup/new?source=google-basecamp).

Answer (score 0):

i guess i won't comment on why tables are a bad idea here (since you specifically mentioned it).  to get the job done you can try this [online table generator](http://www.hooverwebdesign.com/templates/table-generator.html).

if you add to your question with more specific requirements, i will gladly give you some cut and paste code.

Answer (score 0):

My forms are more sophisticated than the typical 2 column ones. I can have 3 &4+ columns and once you start using CSS to layout these columns properly in all browsers, it becomes very time consuming. It is a lot easier to do it with tables and there's nothing wrong with using tables. Tables are used to display tabular data and a form can be thought of as tabular data. There are two camps who can debate tables vs css till eternity about this and it's really pointless. There are millions of sites including known popular ones which use tables for forms and I don't consider that wrong. This is not about using tables for layout, it's about using tables to help in creating forms only.

Comment: You may want to edit the original question to make your intent clear; it reads as if you are advocating pure table-based design for the entire page, as opposed to what you seem to be suggesting here, which is complex table layouts for forms in a larger design. Otherwise, this looks like flamebait.